# When would you save data to the internal cache directory?

Tags: android, caching, android-studio

I am reading through the Android developer [docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteInternalStorage) on saving data and they mention that when saving a file to internal storage you can use either `getFilesDir()` or `getCacheDir()`. When would it be appropriate to save to the cache directory, and what type of data is best saved here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the cache directory to save temporary files. For example, if you're writing a social app (like instagram) and during runtime the app loads  user's pictures, you can store those pictures on the cache directory, so if the user resumes the app while offline, he will still be able to see the last pics.

Make sure to delete each file once it is no longer needed and implement a reasonable size limit for the amount of memory you use at any given time, such as 1MB.

Answer (score 5):

The `getCacheDir()` should only be used for data that is not essential for the running of the app. In other words, you can store data which if unavailable, can be fetched from the server. The reason for this is that the system may delete all the files in the cache dir to reclaim storage space.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html